# Adding a default value to "google custom search"

Tags: search, default, google-custom-search

I would like to automatically add a default value to every item searched in the google custom search bar on my page. For example: if the default value is "review" and the user entered cars into the search field, google will return results for "cars review".

Is this possible?

Thanks ahead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found the answer. If anyone is interested follow the link below - askdavetaylor.com/automatically_add_words_google_search.html